# wget ignorning certain part of url

Tags: php, terminal, wget

wget --output-document=/var/www/projects/meme/upload/1341233172.jpeg http://memecaptain.com/i?u=http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/400x/528461.jpg&t1=dm&t2=cmks

I used following command to download a meme but wget is ignoring &t1 and &t2 part ie the ommand is exccuted as

wget --output-document=/var/www/projects/meme/upload/1341233172.jpeg http://memecaptain.com/i?u=http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/400x/528461.jpg

Any help is appreciated. Bdw I am running the command on terminal as well as in my php script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because ampersand is [special](http://hacktux.com/bash/ampersand). Wrap your url in quotations.

```
wget --output-document=/var/www/projects/meme/upload/1341233172.jpeg \
"http://memecaptain.com/i?u=http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/400x/528461.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes:

```
wget --output-document="/var/www/projects/meme/upload/1341233172.jpeg" "http://memecaptain.com/i?u=http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/400x/528461.jpg&t1=dm&t2=cmks"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do that from a command line, you need to enclose it in quotes. The same if you execute it through shell_exec:

```
 $cmd = "wget --output-document=/var/www/projects/meme/upload/1341233172.jpeg 'http://memecaptain.com/i?u=http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/400x/528461.jpg&t1=dm&t2=cmks'"
 shell_exec($cmd);
```

Otherwise the shell will interpret "&".

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
wget --output-document=/var/www/projects/meme/upload/1341233172.jpeg "http://memecaptain.com/i?u=http://cdn.memegenerator.net/images/400x/528461.jpg&t1=dm&t2=cmks"
```